# Using Pybind with a mulithreaded application results in Exception occurred: The interpreter is already running

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to use pybind11 in my c++ application to call a python file. The c++ application is multithreaded and multiple instances of the class calling python are spun up. I am calling     py::initialize_interpreter() in my constructor of the c++ class and py::finalize_interpreter() in the destructor. I need instance variables preserved in the python file so I cant simply start a scoped interpreter in each function. Id love for any advice on this I am very lost right now. Right now I receive an error Exception occurred: The interpreter is already running. I am assuming this is because I cant have multiple interpreters running.

My constructor:

```
PybindStrategy::PybindStrategy(StrategyID strategyID, const std::string& strategyName, const std::string& groupName):
    Strategy(strategyID, strategyName, groupName) {
    
    py::initialize_interpreter();
 }
```

My destructor:

```
PybindStrategy::~PybindStrategy() {
    py::finalize_interpreter();
}
```

Comment: In addition to creating and destroying the interpreter (why are you doing that anyway? Just spawn one and keep it alive) you need to make sure only one C++ thread is actually doing Python stuff at the same time. A simple `std::mutex` and associated lock shoudl suffice.

Comment: @Botje I have no way to pass a reference to a mutex to each of these threads as I do not control the parent class. Do you have any tips to get around that?

Comment: Any global variable or method will do to host your mutex.